# How to add new entry top top of the list in recyclerView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

Normally when we add new items to recylerview new item comes just below the previous one. I need to bring every new item to top of the list. How can we do so. Thanks

Comment: Try this https://stackoverflow.com/a/32399378/6168272

Answer (score 0):

try the below changes in the XML file.

```
 <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:clipToPadding="false"
    android:scrollbars="none"
    app:layoutManager="LinearLayoutManager"
    app:stackFromEnd="true"
    app:reverseLayout="true/>
```

Answer (score 0):

to add an item to top of the listview instead of adding it to the bottom you have to make it the first element of the your (datasource,array,list ... )
here is one way to make it
{

```
List items = new ArrayList();

//some fictitious objectList where we're populating data
for(Object obj : objectList) {
    items.add(0, obj);
    listAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}

listView.post(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        listView.smoothScrollToPosition(0);
    }
}
```

}